# Google spreadsheets – working formula doesn't work in conditional formatting – is there cell contents in a column on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

There is a sheet Datalist, on it there is a L:L column with a list of URL's.
On another sheet there is the same list, but more complete, and we need to highlight in color those cells that do not have values in 'Datalist'!$L:$L.

When I do this in the neighboring column, I clearly get TRUE / FALSE.

`=IF(iferror(vlookup(G2;'Datalist'!L:L;1;FALSE);TRUE)=TRUE;TRUE();FALSE())`

But in conditional formatting (for G2:G999) the string doesn't work, it doesn't color, although it doesn't write an error either.

`IF(iferror(vlookup(G2;'Datalist'!L:L;1;FALSE);TRUE)=TRUE;TRUE();FALSE())`

The option with "=" at the beginning of the formula gives a formula error and is not saved :(

`=IF(iferror(vlookup(G2;'Datalist'!L:L;1;FALSE);TRUE)=TRUE;TRUE();FALSE())`

Answer (score 1):

Resolved:

```
=IF(iferror(vlookup(G2;indirect("Datalist!$L$3:$L$9999");1;FALSE);TRUE)=TRUE;TRUE;FALSE)
```